# Confusion in database with rating and transation

Tags: sql, database

Let me explain question in my way

**Transaction Table**

*TransactionId,SellerId, BuyerId, ProductId, TransactionPrice, Status*

**RatingTable**

*RatingId, TransactionId, SellerId, BuyerId, ProductId, IsFromBuyer(bit), Rate1, Rate2, Rate3*

Now In my application there will be two entry into rating table. It will be per transaction.
Buyer can rate to seller as well as seller can rate buyer!

Now the problem is How can I identify such buyer/seller has given rating already.

The matter is I want the view in which it will give me data of that transaction + ratedBy(seller/buyer)

Can anyone give me idea?

Look! I can simply fire some query but the thing is I am not sure that rating table must have records! It may have records.

Let me give you more explanation:

I have two view 1) transaction 2) rating

I want that 'view' data (I specified above) on transaction page so I can show/hide rating button.

Comment: "How can I identify such buyer/seller has given rating already? 
 (Don't) Just add a unique index to the table on ."RatingId, TransactionId, SellerId, BuyerId, ProductId, IsFromBuyer(bit)  so that a buyer/seller can't add more than one record and handle the duplicate index error.  Ok re-reading you mean you need to LEFT join transaction to rating so you get transaction and any ratings if they exist...  `SELECT T.*, R.* From Transation T LEFT JOIN Rating R on T.TransactionID = R.TransactionIID AND (T.SellerID = R.SellerID OR T.BuyerID = R.BuyerID)` But it depends on how rating is populated.

Comment: Your rating table structure seems odd to me.  can you describe how transaction and rating table relate and if sellerID and buyerID are always populated? I mean you have the transactionID and can derive the seller/buyerID's so why are they even needed unless you plan on deleting the transaction; and if you do why would you want to keep the rating?  Seems like all you need is ratingID, transactionID, isFromBuyer and Rate1, Rate2, Rate3.  In RDBMS; we try not to duplicate data (unless there's a business need) which appears to be what SellerID and BuyerID are doing in the rating table; do u need?

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on what database vendor you are using but you will just want to join twice on the RatingTable and filter the joins based on your IsFromBuyer column.

It might look something like this in oracle:

```
create or update view TransactionView AS
    select TransactionTable.*, 
           BuyerRating.Rate1 BuyerRate1, BuyerRating.Rate2 BuyerRate2, BuyerRating.Rate3 BuyerRate3, 
           SellerRating.Rate1 SellerRate1, SellerRating.Rate2 SellerRate2, SellerRating.Rate3 SellerRate3
        from TransactionTable 
     left join RatingTable BuyerRating 
          on TransactionTable.TransactionId = BuyerRating.TransactionId
             AND BuyerRating.IsFromBuyer = true
     left join RatingTable SellerRating 
          on TransactionTable.TransactionId = SellerRating.TransactionId
             AND SellerRating.IsFromBuyer = false
```

If there is no BuyerRating row then you would have NULL values in the BuyerRate1/2/3 fields because it is a LEFT JOIN where all TransactionTable rows are included even if there is no matching BuyerRating row to join to in the RatingTable. (Likewise for a missing SellerRating row)

Comment: I think I understand your question and have updated my answer so that your Transaction View will have the 3 BuyerRating values if available and 3 SellerRating values if available on the same row as all your TransactionTable values.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the RatingID, and you want to get both entries for the Transaction:

```
SELECT * FROM TransactionTable x
INNER JOIN RatingTable y
ON x.TransactionID = y.TransactionID
WHERE TransactionID in (SELECT TransactionID from RatingTable where RatingID = 1234)
```

Comment: Rating table may have antry ! If its not then ?